# Width issue with input in table's thead th

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table which has a peculiar style issue when I insert an input element in the header.  It does not center the input exactly; instead it is off by 2 pixels on the right side.  I have some Twitter Bootstrap styles applied to the table, but I can't find one that is causing the issue so I don't think that has anything to do with it.  Here is the markup:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%;">
            <a href="#">ID</a>
            <input type="text" value="" class="grid-filter" id="id-filter">
        </th>
    ...
```

Here is a picture of the issue (zoomed in considerably):

[image]

Here are the styles applied:

```
th { 
    width: 15%; 

    a { display: block; }

    input {
        height: 15px;
        line-height: 15px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

In the image above, I'm using Firebug and have focused on the "ID" anchor.  As you can see, the anchor is correctly centered in the th, but the input box has an extra 2 pixels on the right for some reason.  Why is this?  The weird thing is that this does NOT affect select elements, only input elements.

Update: When I set the border and outline, Bootstrap's focus glow also has a border.  Not sure which style to override...

[image]

Comment: What is the computed style on the `input`? It probably has a `border: 1px`

Comment: Tom: It is, but I want/need a border.

Comment: does `input:focus { outline: none; }` do the trick?

Comment: It does initially, but when the animation occurs when focus is lost, the outline returns momentarily.  The input in focus also doesn't have the border and looks a little weird.  I think I'm going to go with your solution to add a border: 1px; and outline: 1px solid #ccc, and just set the box-shadow: none; for input:focus.  I can live without that animation.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** looks like the problem is your `width` attribute. Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbRVf/)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 5%;">
                <a href="#">ID</a>
                <input type="text" value="" class="grid-filter" id="id-filter"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
a, input {    
    padding: 0;
    margin 0;
}

a { 
    display: block;
    background: red;     
}

input {
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    /* width: 100%; */
}

table { width: 3em }
```

The `width` attribute on the `input` defaults to `auto`, which does what you want in this case.

Comment: That appears to work, but I want a border.  Why does the border end messing up the centering of the input element by affecting the right (and bottom) padding/margins?

Comment: I've edited the answer so that the input has a non-zero border.

Comment: If I set the width to auto, it overrides the th's width.  The only way I can get the input to be the full th width with padding is making the width 100%.  Also, the border/outline fix you supplied previously will need additional fixes with Bootstrap.  When in focus, input's have a blue glow which also has an outline now.  Pic in original post.